# DXA Resolver - activate log

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

I need to check how it's working DXA Resolver but I don't find how to activate debug logs for this resolver.

how can I activate it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DXA Resolver uses a non-standard logging mechanism which can be activated by setting an environment variable called `DXA_LOGGING` with the path of the log file.

See https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/master/Sdl.Web.DXAResolver/LogAdaptor.cs