# DXA Custom Resolver started

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa2.2, dxa-dotnet

DXA Custom Resolver installer should do a gac install of assembly and a Content Management Environment (CME) plugin install.
In the development environment, the CME plugin is not correct it shows only the publishing page in "Items to publish".

With [dxa resolver activate log](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20762/dxa-resolver-activate-log) logs more items. Publishing works as aspected.
We use CTs with the setting "Publish Embedded on a Page".

Question-1:

How to install the CME plugin without destroying the custom resolver?
The need for this is only visibility for the end-user?

Question-2:

Custom Resolver function only runs for publishing and re-publish runs.
Why is the unpublish page not implemented in the dxa custom resolver [here on entry point "public void Resolve"](https://github.com/RWS/dxa-content-management/blob/develop/Sdl.Web.DXAResolver/Resolver.cs) ?
The Unpublish page will return immediately.

```
 if (instruction.Purpose != ResolvePurpose.Publish && instruction.Purpose != ResolvePurpose.RePublish ||
            _maxRecurseDepth == 0)
            return;
```

Only unpublish on individual components works.

Question-3:

Custom Resolver should be extended with unpublish in its own assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answers1:**

DXA Installer package comes with DXA Custom Resolver Installation script to add the DXA Custom Resolver to the CMS/Publishing server's GAC and add or modifies the **Tridion.ContentManager.config** also Copying DXA UI Extension resource files.

Download this https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/releases/download/DXA_2.2.9_Hotfix/SDL.DXA.NET.2.2.9.zip file and copy it to the CMS/Publishing server's

Run this below command to install or update.

> D:_Install\SDL.DXA.NET.2.2.9\cms> .\cms-customresolver.ps1
> -extensionTargetFolder "D:\DXAResolver" -cmSiteName "Tridion Sites Content Manager" -useHttpsEndpoint $true

**Answers2:**

If you take a look into the unpublishing dialog, there is no option to unpublish linked items.

So the behavior you see is expected, only that Component should be resolved and unpublished.

Availability of that option for publishing action makes sense to update item (Component) that might be an embedded peace of linked component.

While for unpublishing action R&D would expect customers will choose top content in the chain to avoid unexpected unpublishing of the content in other places.

**Answers3:**

Yes It's possible, I had some similar requirements, but Rick has pointed out that we could best use the event system to adjust link resolving behavior for Component (instead of Custom Resolver).

```
args.PublishInstruction.ResolveInstruction.IncludeComponentLinks = false;
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks. For answer-1: We already have DXA.NET.2.2.6 can we use this 2.2.9 for this update part only?

Comment: For answer-3: 
We use dxa CT's with "Published Embedded on a Page". We have to write own code in the event system for unpublising components that where skipped by the default dxa custom resolver. Follow the links and check if component exist on other page(s) (not the current).  These are components which are not directly on the page. Right?

Comment: @FritsLesterhuis, answer your both comments' questions. yes. 2.2.6 to 2.2.9 not many changes to CM TBBs and customer resolver side. you can use a later one, 2nd question answer is also yes.